# Why I am unable to copy data from one table to another?

Tags: postgresql

I use the following script to transfer data from one table to another in seperate databases:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# rds.example.com is a CNAME to an RDS Database
HOST='rds.example.com'
HOST_DB='log_usr'
PORT=5432
TABLE='log'
USER='some_user'

ARCHIVING_HOST='192.168.10.72'
ARCHIVING_DB='archiving'
ARCHIVING_PORT=5432
ARCHIVING_TABLE='log'
ARCHIVING_USER='archiving'

rows_to_archive=$(psql -qtAX -h ${HOST} -p ${PORT} -U ${USER}  ${HOST_DB} -c "SELECT count(*) FROM ${TABLE} WHERE created_at <= $TRANSACTION_TIME_formated;")

echo $rows_to_archive" will be archived"

num_rows_before=$(psql -qtAX -h ${ARCHIVING_HOST} -p ${ARCHIVING_PORT} -U ${ARCHIVING_USER}  ${ARCHIVING_DB} -c "SELECT count(*) FROM ${ARCHIVING_TABLE} ;")

echo "BEFORE ARCHIVING ROWS IN ${ARCHIVING_HOST}:${ARCHIVING_TABLE} : "$num_rows_before

echo "Backup Database"
psql -h $HOST -p $PORT -U ${USER} $HOST_DB -c "COPY (select * from $TABLE where created_at <= $TRANSACTION_TIME_formated) TO STDOUT CSV" | psql -h $ARCHIVING_HOST -p $ARCHIVING_PORT -U $ARCHIVING_USER $ARCHIVING_DB -c "COPY ${ARCHIVING_TABLE} FROM STDIN CSV"

num_rows_after=$(psql -qtAX -h ${ARCHIVING_HOST} -p ${ARCHIVING_PORT} -U ${ARCHIVING_USER}  ${ARCHIVING_DB} -c "SELECT count(*) FROM ${ARCHIVING_TABLE} ;")
echo "AFTER ARCHIVING ROWS IN ${ARCHIVING_HOST}:${ARCHIVING_TABLE}"$num_rows_after


if [[ "$num_rows_before" == "$num_rows_after" ]];then
  echo "FAIL"
  exit 1
fi
```

And Once I run it seems to be unable to transfer the data because the rows in `archiving.log` has not been increased.

In Both databases `log` table has the following structure:

```
id: PK
value: TEXT
created_at: TIMESTAMP DEFAULTS(NOW())
```

And the output of the script is:

```
1000 will be archived
BEFORE ARCHIVING ROWS IN 192.168.10.72:archiving 100000
Backup Database
AFTER ARCHIVING ROWS IN 192.168.10.72:archiving 100000
FAIL
```

Do you have any idea why the count has not increased at all?
I mean I do transfer data from on table to another and error output is a seperate in bash.

Comment: Try running the command directly with no parameters using the CLI - type them in directly!

Comment: A succesful copy would have reported "COPY 1000", twice.  What is "$TRANSACTION_TIME_formated" ?  ..._formaTTed ?